# python executable file in windows

Tags: python, executable

Okay, I'm completely new to this.

I created a python script that imports `tkinter`. On my Ubuntu, I can execute the program from the terminal program. Till now there is no problem. However, my friends asked if I could deliver the program to them so that they could use it on their PC. They have 0 knowledge of programming and they use Windows -.-. So my question is, how I can create an executable file from Ubuntu so that it can run under Windows? I've already read something about py2exe, but I could not manage installing it. If

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use py2exe on plain Ubuntu. It needs to run from Windows. Right now, py2exe doesn't work well with Wine. Do you not have access to any Windows computers (maybe one of your friends')?

You can also get your friends to install Python on their Windows machines and teach them how to run your programs, if you're willing to put in the extra effort.

Comment: Teaching your friends to program is quite hard unless they are good at learning (or conversely you are good at teaching). But +1 as i was going to suggest the same thing.

Comment: Ah well, yeah I can use my friend's pc. Thanks for the help

Comment: @James it wouldn't really require teaching them how to program, so much as teaching them how to use the command prompt to run a Python script.

Comment: @James Khoury, neither I have the energy to teach them nor they are willing to learn. We are all political scientist students but apparently I am the only one interested in programming lol

Comment: @Rafe True but then you're probably better setting it all up for them and creating a shortcut to run it for them.

Comment: Teaching them how to double-click a python script after having installed a python interpreter should be enough, really.

Comment: @wobble I've had to teach people to double-click and right-click and click-and-drag so I agree it can be enough ... more than enough.